# jQuery automatically select first option when it is a single select

Tags: jquery, select

There are two multiselects used in my project, a single select and a multiple select. At first, they are disabled and show right(display the noneSelectedText value). If I enable them, the single select always automatically select the first option, and the multiple one show right.Then disable them, both of them show right again.
My question is that how can I stop the single select one from automatically selecting the first option? 
I tried to uncomment the code following in the source code of multiselect,

```
    // browsers automatically select the first option
    // by default with single selects
    if(isSelected && !o.multiple) {
      labelClasses.push('ui-state-active');      
    }
```

but it does not work.
Did I miss something or do something wrong?

Comment: As far as I know the only option is to give a default option as the first option in the select... like `....Select xxx...` then if it is selected then do not consider it

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, with an unselectable option :

```
<select placeholder="coudcou">
    <option val="null" disabled selected> select an answer</option>
    <option val="one">one</option>
</select>

$('select').on('change', function(){
    $('select option:disabled').remove();
});
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bd4R7/1/